# A question about mysql timestamp query fuzzy range

Tags: mysql, timestamp, fuzzy-search

thank you for you answer!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rohPp.png)
table is this picture

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    vehicle_warning_message v 
    WHERE 
    v.capture_time >= "2023-10-03%" 
    AND v.capture_time <= "2023-11-03%";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g5r4.png)
Why can the value of 2023-11-03 be displayed, but not the value of 2023-10-03? The two values are the maximum time of the day, namely "2023-10-03 23:59:59" and "2023-11-03 23:59:59".

Comment: `%` symbol works only in `LIKE`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Wildcards (`%` or `_`) only work in a `LIKE` statement, and only on character (string) data. Outside that `LIKE` statement, it's just a plain character. You should find a good SQL tutorial to learn the basics of using the language. It will save you a lot of wasted time in the future if you learn  those basics instead of just flailing around throwing in code you don't understand.

Comment: @Ken White I just want to know why this phenomenon occurs and whether it has anything to do with the source code.

Comment: I've already explained that - wildcards are **only valid in a LIKE clause, and only with character data. Outside that LIKE statements, they are simply characters** and are treated like any other character. `2023-11-03` is less than or equal to `2023-11-03%`, but `2023-10-03` is NOT greater than `2023-10-03`, because `2023-10-03` is shorter (because it doesn't have the `%` sign. You'll find you have the same problem if you replace both of the `%`s with `a` or `X` or any other character. It's not a *phenomenon* - it's simply basic SQL.

Comment: @Ken White ok ok , thank you for your answer,i understand , Could you recommend some mysql books for me?

Comment: No. Google can find you books and tutorials. Your question here is about plain old SQL, not anything specific to MySQL. Any good tutorial can teach you the basics of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If your date-time column is of type string, then the expression '>= "2023-10-03%"' means to search for all values in alphabetical order greater than or equal to '2023-10-03%'. The percent sign is a symbol above which the search will not search in the ASCI table. Therefore, "2023-10-03" is not displayed.